# Problems with constructor resolution order

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, implicit-conversion

Consider the following constructors for T:

```
struct T {
    T(const bool) { std::cout << "T(const bool)" << endl; }
    T(const std::string&) { std::cout << "T(const std::string&)" << endl; }
};

T t("");
```

1. Why does `T(const bool)` take precedence over `T(const std::string&)` when constructing t?
2. Since the above precedence might cause confusion to users expecting `T(const std::string&)` to be called, what can I do to have `T(const std::string&)` implicitly called when passing string literals to the constructor of T. For now the only work around I have found is to add another constructor, which takes the highest precedence:

   ```
   T(const char* s)
   {
       std::cout << "T(const char*)" << endl;
       *this = std::string(s);
   }
   ```
3. Apart from the above solution, declaring `explicit T(const bool)` to avoid confusion does not solve the above problem: in this case, although `T t = ""` is now prohibited, why is the form `T t("")` is still allowed and does call `T(const bool)` ?

Answer (score 8):

**Why does `T(const bool)` take precedence over `T(const std::string&)` when constructing `t`?**

`""` is of type `char[1]`; this is implicitly convertible to `char const*` via the array-to-pointer conversion.  A pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool`, with all non-null pointers becoming `true` and all null pointers becoming `false`.  These are both "built-in" standard conversions.

The `char const* -> std::string` conversion is a user-declared conversion:  it utilizes a converting constructor of `std::string` that takes a `char const*`.

The standard ("built-in") conversions are preferred over user-declared conversions during overload resolution, so the constructor taking `bool` is a better match here than the one taking `std::string`.

**For now the only work around I have found is to add another constructor**

That sounds like a reasonable solution; certainly the most straightforward solution for the simple scenario you describe.  Your use of assignment to `*this` is a bit clumsy, though; it would be better either to have both constructors delegate to some initialization function.

Alternatively, you could use a template with `enable_if` for any constructors for which you would like to disallow conversions:

```
template <typename U>
T(U, std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, bool>::value>::type* = 0) { }
```

This constructor will only be callable with a `bool` argument and nothing else.  You can find `enable_if` and `is_same` in Boost, C++ TR1, or C++0x.  You could also use `!is_pointer`, `is_integral`, or some other combination of type traits to allow for some other argument types but not `char const*`.

Or, as another alternative, you might eschew `bool` altogether and use your own enumeration with enumerators corresponding to `true` and `false` for the constructor.  Whether this makes sense depends on your use case.

**Declaring `explicit T(const bool)` to avoid does not solve the above problem...why is the form `T t("")` is still allowed and does call `T(const bool)`?**

`explicit` only disallows implicit conversions to `T`.  `T t("");` has no conversions to `T` at all; it directly initializes the object `t` by constructing it with the argument `""` passed to whichever constructor matches best.

Comment: `enable_if` should end with `...::type* = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

`""` can convert to both `std::string` and `bool`.

The question is, which way will it convert?

- Conversion to `std::string` is a user-defined conversion.
- Conversion to `bool` is a standard conversion.

So the answer is, standard conversion has higher precedence over user-defined conversion. So `""` will convert to `bool`.

Example,

```
struct A
{
   A(int i) {} //i.e an int can implicity convert to A
};

void f(const A &) { cout << "User-defined conversion won" << endl; }
void f(const bool &) { cout << "Standard conversion won" << endl; }

int main() {
        f (10);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Standard conversion won
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/5Bt0K

In the above demo, `10` can convert to `A` and `bool` both. Since converting to `bool` is a standard conversion, it converts into `bool`, instead of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Because a user-defined conversion is not considered if a built-in one is available.

Use the third constructor, one that takes `const char*`. There's no better way.

Comment: "There's no better way."  I beg to differ.

Comment: @James McNellis: Your method with `enable_if` looks nice indeed.